# Debugging header only c++ code xcode 11 (breakpoints don't always work)

Tags: c++, xcode, inline, breakpoints

I am having problems debugging header-only C++ code in Xcode 11. I assume it is because the compiler is inlining the methods, and that is fine for release code, but it makes it impossible to put breakpoints in the code.

If this is indeed the issue, I cannot seem to find a way to turn the inlining off for debug purposes. The optimization level is already -O0 for my debug build. If I move the method(s) in question to an implementation file instead of a header file, debugging works fine. But I don't want to do this, the project I'm working on is well suited to header-only development.

I've spent about an hour googling WRT this, but it's led nowhere.

Has anyone else ran into this problem? Is there any way out?

Comment: Unfortunately, there's little that can be done here. Been there, share your pain just have to plow your way and think of ways to make debugging useful. No one size fits all fix. Depends on the actual code.

Comment: have you tacked a -g onto the command line for the extra debugging info?

Comment: Adding -fno-inline-functions to the compile flags might be what you're looking for?

Comment: -fno-inline-functions didn't seem to help - that surprised me